# How to map two tables like primary key and foreign key in JPA Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I have these two tables and want to map the userName fields so that I can query messages of a specific user only. How can I do this ?

```
@Entity
public class User {
    
    
    @Id
    private String userName;
}


@Entity(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID messageID;
    String message;
    String userName;
    Long timeStamp;
    boolean isSent;

}
```

The mapping should be done between userName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToMany` mapping based on your relationship using `@JoinColumn` as shown in below.

```
@Entity
public class User {    
    
    @Id
    private String userName;
   
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "userName", referencedColumnName = "userName")
    List<Message> messages;
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID messageID;
    String message;
    String userName;
    Long timeStamp;
    boolean isSent;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please answer this as well ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64098263/how-to-select-a-custom-page-in-pagination-by-a-exising-value

Answer (score 1):

Just add your another entity in your current entity class, jpa automatically map your entity classes using primary key.

```java
@Entity
public class User { 
    
    @Id
    private String userName;
    private Message message;

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please answer this as well ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64098263/how-to-select-a-custom-page-in-pagination-by-a-exising-value