# How to select a custom page in pagination by a exising value?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination and I have a unique ID object of UUID, I want the page start to be from where the unique ID exists, if the input param UUID is on 50th page, I want to start from 50th page, how can I do this ?

My current implementation is below:

```
public List<Message> getAllMessages(User user, Integer limit, UUID id)
{
    Pageable paging  = PageRequest.of(0, limit, Sort.by("timeStamp"));
    List<Message> list = messageRepository.findByUser(user, paging);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: How the query defined in respository ?

Comment: It's not going to be possible without first calculating the page index on which the UUID can be found, in a separate query, I'm afraid.